# code to "finish off a graph"

Tags: c#, math

I want to graph from one date to another date and i only partial data now

For example, i have data points for each month from jan 2010 to march 2010 but i want a line graph with a data point for each month for all of 2010.

i basically want to take the slope of the current points and create new points for each future month of 2010 to fill in for the graph.

Comment: Sounds like http://xkcd.com/605/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [Linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Be careful, however, of [*extrapolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extrapolation) beyond the boundaries of the data set you already have. For example, having three data points for the first three months of the year does not imply anything useful about November.

Comment: The requirement sounds more like extrapolation than interpolation.

Comment: @Hightechrider - do you know of any csharp libraries that have these functions built in ?

Comment: Extrapolation can indeed imply useful data about future dates. It all depends on what is being extrapolated, and how much you know about it.
If, for example, the quantity measured is "money in a jar" and you deposit an approximately equal sum of money in the jar every month, and intend to do so the entire year, then the extrapolation for November will be very useful.
The xkcd comic Mark listed in his comment does however show a good example where extrapolation is silly.

Answer (score 1):

[Linear extrapolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation#Linear_extrapolation) (the linked page has the formula).